# How do I create a formtastic nested input without fieldset?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, nested, formtastic, polymorphism

I have a table `User` that inherits from a table called `Person`

Long story short, instead of having to do the following:

```
f.inputs 'Something' do
  f.inputs for: :person do |f|
    f.input :name
    f.input :surname
  end
  f.input :account
end
```

This generates an `fieldset` inside an `ol`, which is by itself invalid, but that's not what worries me. I want to get rid of the `fieldset` so all the attributes are shown at the same level.

```
f.inputs 'Something' do
  f.input :name, for: :person
  f.input :surname, for: :person
  f.input :account
end
```

Of course that is not valid, there is not such thing as a for: in the input.

I was thinking about using delegate, but then I though that I also have a lot of `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in the `Person` model and them would broke.

Also the `Person` table is being inherited by another model.

There is any gem that transparentize this and allow me to just inherit the model?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `semantic_fields_for` instead of `inputs`:

```
f.inputs 'Something' do
  f.semantic_fields_for :person do |p|
    p.input :name
    p.input :surname
  end
  f.input :account
end
```